# How to assign an ID value to each added row in a .txt file (ASP.NET MVC / C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I currently have a program where a user enters a text value into a text input, this text value is then written to a .txt file ("Category.txt") saved withing app_data. I need to assign an ID value (0, 1, 2, 3... etc.) to each user text input within this .txt file. Therefore an example row within the .txt file would be something like:

apple, 0

banana, 1

peach, 2

lemon, 3 ..

and so forth. (The ID's must be hidden from the user, as these are automatically assigned upon submitting of the text input).

I am completely lost on how i would go about doing this, the program needs to be written in C# code, so far i have this:

```
[HttpPost]

public ActionResult Category(string categoryDescription)
{

     var dataFile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Category.txt");

     var indexLine = System.IO.File.ReadLines(dataFile).Last();



     var textFileData = categoryDescription + " " + indexLine + Environment.NewLine;

     System.IO.File.AppendAllText(dataFile, textFileData);

     return View();

}
```

I am really quite unsure on what could be used to count the rows as new content is submitted.. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Simply you can use a static Dictionary: at the beginning you can initialize that from the text file, after you add values to the dictionary while you are adding them to the file.

If you want to simplify all, try using Newtonsoft.Json to serialize / deserialize data to file.

Comment: Unfortunately i am quite unfamiliar with Newtonsoft.Json, so i really am not too sure on how i would carry out your suggestion.. apologies on my behalf

Comment: No problem: quite powerful but not mandatory (try to watch how that work as soon as possible, very much important if you do MVC).

Comment: Definetly will do, thanks man :)

Answer (score 2):

I found a pretty easy way of doing this using the following code;

```
public ActionResult Category(string categoryDescription)
        {

            var dataFile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Category.txt");

            var numberOfLines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(dataFile).Count();                           

            var textFileData = categoryDescription + "," + numberOfLines + Environment.NewLine;

            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(dataFile, textFileData);

            return View();

        }
```

I basically just assigned the number of rows to a variable which will obviously accumulate as the user submits more and more text inputs.